# Symfony: question about a piece of code of sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: symfony1

there is this code below in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

```
$a = sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url');

var_dump($a);

$signinUrl = sfConfig::get('app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url', $user->getReferer($request->getReferer()));

var_dump($signinUrl);

var_dump($user->getReferer($request->getReferer()));
```

It prints this:

> null
>
> string
>   'http://rs3.localhost/frontend_dev.php/'
>   (length=38)
>
> string
>   'http://rs3.localhost/frontend_dev.php/miembros' (length=46)

I don't know why the the second and the third lines are different..any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird.  Spooky.

I wonder if maybe the two calls to `getReferer()` are in different contexts?  Maybe the first (as the second arg to `sfConfig::get()`) implicitly uses `__toString()` whereas when you use `var_dump()`, maybe it's printing the raw value of the referer object?

Hrmm... the API says `getReferer()` returns a string, so that's probably not it.

What are you trying to do, BTW?  Is it not honoring your `app_sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url` setting from `app.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

sfDoctrineGuardPlugin sets a `referer` attribute in the user, so that it can redirect back to the page originally requested. When you call `getReferer` it removes the attribute. (This is causing bugs for me, which is what brought me here.)

Answer (score 0):

yitznewton pointed me towards a solution. The sfGuardSecurityUser class uses a method setReferer that saves a referer attribute but only if one is not yet set.

If somehow you manage to get to the executeSignin method in the sfGuard actions twice only the first referer attribute will be saved, this means that the second time the referer in the request and the referer in the user attribute can be different.

The getReferer method removes that attribute, and falls back to the request referer when the attribute is not set. this explains why calling $user->getReferer($request->getReferer()) twice returns different values sometimes.

The solution i found was to overwrite the setReferer method of the sfGuardSecurityUser in the myUser class:

```
public function setReferer($referer) {
    $this->setAttribute('referer', $referer);
}
```

So far i have not found any side effects, this change ensures the user attribute will allways be the most recent, however there has to be a reason to explain why the symfony folk chose to implement this as it was.

Ive tested this by switching between apps on the login screen, allowing the session to die, killing the session manually and normally using the application and so far i have not found any side effects.